# Export a php page to pdf

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf-generation

I have a php page which consists of table data and a few funnel charts. I want to export the page to pdf with headers and footers.

Can anybody tell me how to export it using javascript or jquery or in any other form?

Thank You

Comment: try `mPdf` or `fPdf` PHP libraries ...

Comment: you can use [DOMPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) for pdf export.

Comment: As you are using the PHP to generate the page, I think best option is to use the TCPDF package. It has so power to do so many customization and lot easier to config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for using FPDF you can download from the link and for more information , Here's [http://fpdf.org](http://fpdf.org/)

after that you can integrate as follows..

```
<?php

require_once('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        $query='your query';
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); // data from database 


        $this->SetXY(50,60);
        $this->Cell(45,6,'Name  :',1,1,'R');
        $this->SetXY(95,60);
        $this->Cell(80,6,$row['pdf_name'],1,1);

        $this->SetXY(50,66);
        $this->Cell(45,6,'Email Address  :',1,1,'R');
        $this->SetXY(95,66);
        $this->Cell(80,6,$row['pdf_email'],1,1);

        $this->SetXY(50,72);
        $this->Cell(45,6,'Question Paper Selected  :',1,1,'R');
        $this->SetXY(95,72);
        $this->Cell(80,6,$row['subject_sel'],1,1);

        $this->SetXY(50,78);
        $this->Cell(45,6,'Total Correct Answers  :',1,1,'R');
        $this->SetXY(95,78);
        $this->Cell(80,6,$row['right_answered'],1,1);

        $this->SetXY(50,84);
        $this->Cell(45,6,'Percentage  :',1,1,'R');
        $this->SetXY(95,84);
        $this->Cell(80,6,$row['percentage']."%",1,1);

        $this->Ln(20);
    }
    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'abc according to you',0,0,'C');
    }
}
$pdf=new PDF('P','mm',array(297,210));
$pdf->Output($name.'.pdf','D');
?>
```

you can edit according to your need, it will display record in the form of table and generate it to pdf. hope it will helpful to you.

**update:**

for image

```
$this->Image('image path',80,30,50);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yadav i found it as useful for my requirement

Comment: Can u tel me how to add an table and graph using fpdf....i have a page with some tables and funnel charts one after another...let me know how i can add it in the above code

Comment: @mac does your chart in image form?

Comment: @you have to make table manually as i have made it according to my need and for image let me give you way

Comment: funnel charts are in image format..

Comment: @mac then good you can load image as i have edited the answer at bottom